# Modify button template in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this button with a style template attached that i wish to modify in the code-behind.

Here is the button:

```
<Button x:Name="But6" Content="6" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource ExitButton}"/>
```

It's style template:

```
<Style x:Key="ExitButton" x:Name="exitButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter x:Name="exitButtonSetter" Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name="exitButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="exitButtonRectangle" Stroke="#6d6d6d" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RadiusX="15" RadiusY="15" Width="500" Height="150" Margin="10,10,-600,10"/>
                    <Label x:Name="exitButtonLabel" Content="Exit" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="22" Margin="75,0,0,0" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="exitButtonRectangle" Property="Fill" Value="#9c9c9c"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can i modify things like the Margin property of a Rectangle or the Content of a Label of a template in the code-behind?

My failed attempt:

```
But6.ExitButton.exitButton.Template.exitButtonRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Comment: your Rectange has a name (exitButtonRectangle). Do exitButtonRectangle.Margin? Or is this not an Option?

Comment: use Template.FindName to get Rectangle and then set margin

Comment: I see, but im confused about what the second argument should be because it wants a FrameworkElementobject: But6.Template.FindName("exitButtonRectangle", ?).margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!